# How to merge f string with b string in one line usage in Python

Tags: python, f-string

I can create **b-sting** this way:
`name_binary = b'Adam'`
but if I have variable like `name='Adam'` and I want to make at once usage of **f-string** and **b-string**:
`name_binary = fb'{name}'`
I get:

```
   File "<input>", line 1
    c = fb'{a}'
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that I can do:
`name_binary = name.encode('utf-8')`

But technicality is that possible by using **b** and **f** together as on my example?

Comment: How would Python know which encoding should be used for your variable then ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, what you want has been proposed but rejected till now.

Read more about it in [PEP-489](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#no-binary-f-strings):

> **No binary f-strings**
>
> For the same reason that we don't support `bytes.format()`, you may not
>   combine `'f'` with `'b'` string literals.

---

The options you have (like you already mentioned) would be:

```
name_binary = f'{name}'.encode('utf-8')
```

or

```
name_binary = name.encode('utf-8')
```